# Series finds value through direct == comparison but fails on isin() process

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

I am trying to filter a dataframe through this method:

```
filter = (df_1['Year']==2022) & **(df_1['Quarter'].isin(['2022Q3','2022Q4']))**
df_incumbent = df_1[filter].groupby(['Lane','Carrier Scac','Quarter']).agg({'Cust Linehaul':np.mean,'Load Number':'count'}).unstack('Quarter',fill_value='NaN')
df_incumbent
```

And it returns nothing. However when I do a direct comparison item by item it returns a dataframe.

```
filter = (df_1['Year']==2022) & (df_1['Quarter']=='2022Q3')
```

Some more information on the df_1['Quarter']. If it helps with some clue.

```
df_1['Quarter'].unique()

<PeriodArray>
['2021Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q3', '2021Q2', '2022Q1', '2022Q2', '1970Q1',
    'NaT', '2022Q3', '2022Q4']
Length: 10, dtype: period[Q-DEC]
```

I have used `isin` successfully by passing a list of items, but not sure why this one is not working. I tried to go through other questions, but not able to still solve it.

Comment: "filter" is build-in Python function. Do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks. I have used filter in the past and as I said when I used directly it worked. Nonetheless, I changed it to something else, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RajibLochanSarkar it worked fine for me when i created some test data of int years and string quarters. maybe the dtype of the quarter is different for you? would using `.astype(str)`  solve it ?

Comment: Yes that solved the problem. As you see there the dtype is period[Q-DEC]. How should they be passed in the list with the str format I mean '2022Q3' or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `isin` only works on list with the same dtype, try create PeriodIndex first:

```
df_1['Quarter'].isin(pd.PeriodIndex(['2022Q3','2022Q4'], freq='Q'))
```

Example:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(['2022-10-01', '2023-10-02']).to_period('Q-DEC')
s
# PeriodIndex(['2022Q4', '2023Q4'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]')

s.isin(['2022Q4'])
# array([False, False])

s.isin(pd.PeriodIndex(['2022Q4'], freq='Q'))
# array([ True, False])
```